# "die Lehre von der Deutsche Politik [dass] wir heute haben gehabt" - What's the right word instead of "dass"?

Tags: word-choice

The sentence is:

> Ah, das ist sehr klug von dir! Was dachtest du über die Lehre von der Deutsche Politik [dass] wir heute haben gehabt?

I know this *dass* is incorrect, but what is the correct word for it?

Comment: Anyway which word you use instead of *dass*: This sentence is grammatically incorrect. I think it is a wrong translation of an English sentence. Could you please post that English sentence? Maybe then we can understand what this sentence wants to tell us, and then maybe we will be able to find the right word.

Comment: What is it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more incorrect in that sentence than only the *dass*.
Assuming that you want to express a question like "What are you thinking about that lesson of German politics we had today?", I'd suggest something like

> Was hältst Du von der Lehrstunde in deutscher Politik, welche wir heute gehabt haben?

or

> Was denkst Du über die Lektion, die wir heute bezüglich deutscher Politik hatten?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [relative pronouns.](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/sentence-structure/dependent-clauses/relative-clauses)

The object that you are referring to from the main clause is called the antecedent, and its gender and position in the second clause determine which pronoun to use. In this case `Wir haben [die Lehre] gehabt` is your second clause, where Lehre is in the accusative case and it is a feminine noun so your sentence becomes:

> Ah, das ist sehr klug von dir! Was dachtest du über die Lehre von der Deutsche Politik, die wir heute haben gehabt?